# Antlr works Syntax diagram not generated despite Of true grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, antlrworks

I am trying to make a compiler like a C .I entered my grammar into antlrWorks IDE and it show no error and but when I want to see the syntax diagram of my rules it complained that " cannot display rule 'xxxxx' because start state not found". I didn't find any special way for defining start symbol on the examples.I put my grammar here may be somebody can help me:

```
grammar MiniC;

tokens {
    GET='get';
    PUT='put';
    CHANGE='change';
    DATA='data';
    METADATA='metadata';
    DEPENDENCIES='dependencies';
    DEPENDENTS='dependents';
    STATISTICS='statistics';
    FROM='from';
    IN='in';
    ABOUT='about';
    OF='of';
    MAIN='main()';
    ID = 'ID';
    SEMI = ';';
    INT ='int';
    VOID = 'void';
    BOOL ='BOOL';
    FLOAT = 'FLOAT';
    IF = 'if';
    ELSE = 'else';
    RETURN = 'return';
    BREAK ='break';
    WHILE ='while';
};

program
    :    MAIN compound_stmt
    ;

compound_stmt
    :
    '{' local_declarations stmt_list'}'
    ;

local_declarations
    :
    () (var_declarations)*
    ;

var_declarations
    :
    type_specifier ID SEMI 
    |
    type_specifier ID [('0'..'9')*]
    ;

type_specifier 
    :   
    'int'
    |
    'void'
    |
    'bool'
    |
    'float'     
    ;

stmt_list 
    :
    (stmt)*
    ;   

stmt : 
    expression_stmt
    |
    compound_stmt
    |
    selection_stmt
    |
    iteration_stmt
    |
    return_stmt
    |
    break_stmt
    ;

selection_stmt 
    :   IF('('expression')') compound_stmt
        |
        IF('('expression')') compound_stmt ELSE compound_stmt
        ;
iteration_stmt 
    :
        WHILE ('('expression')') compound_stmt; 

return_stmt 
    :
        RETURN SEMI|RETURN expression;

break_stmt 
    :   BREAK;

expression_stmt 
    :
        expression; 

expression
    :   var '=' simple_expression|simple_expression;

simple_expression 
    :
        operand operator operand;
operand :
    ('1'..'9')
    |
    ;

var     :
        ID|ID[('1'..'9')*];

operator 
    :       
    RelOp|LogicOp|ArithOp;

RelOp   :   
    '<='|'<'|'>='|'>'|'!='|'==' ;
LogicOp :   
    '&&'|'||'
    ;

ArithOp :   
    '+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'%';    


WS
    :) (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();}
    ;
```

Comment: The grammar is far from "true", and I really don't believe ANTLRWorks does not complain when generating a lexer and parser. While glancing over your grammar, I see at least 4 errors. What version of ANTLRWorks are you using? Is it really the grammar you posted, or did you post a different version of it?

Comment: @BartKiers, actually yes, this grammar contains a lot of errors. But the error in AntlrWorks 'cannot display rule 'x....' is shown because of semicolon, which was placed after 'tokens {...}' description.

Comment: well, that's my point: the grammar is not 'true'... Did you resolve it now?

Comment: no, until now I didn't find my mistakes in grammar. I omit semicolon as Andremonity said but antlrworks show no error .I am using antlr 3.5-rc-2 and antlrworks 1.5

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove semicolon ( `;` ) after

```
tokens {
    ...
} *;*
```

So, it must be just:

```
tokens {
    ...
}
```

This is the main reason why `AntlrWorks` says "*cannot display rule 'xxxxx' because start state not found*" (I checked this). 
But after this correction you will probably see several new errors in your grammar, which are actually present, but this is already an another question.